NextJS Prerender/build Error - Works fine in Dev, breaks in Build
I am building a portfolio website in NextJS and everything is working fine locally.
When I try to run npm run build, I get a Prerender Error. The documentation didn't really help.
Here's the error:
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more:
ReferenceError: location is not defined
at 8550 (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/app/page.js:1:24220)
at t (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
at 7853 (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/app/page.js:1:13283)
at t (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
at 6239 (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/app/page.js:1:2765)
at t (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
at 9079 (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/app/page.js:6:97578)
at Object.t [as require] (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
at require (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18365)
at I (/Users/rossritchie/code/react-portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94362)
✓ Generating static pages (5/5)

Export encountered errors on following paths:

Not sure why I'm getting this error on build - from what I've read this happens where there is cross page navigation but its a simple/static webpage (although one of the libraries accesses 'Embla API?).
file structure attached.
'use client'
import Image from "next/image";
import Head from "next/head";
import {BsFillMoonStarsFill} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {AiFillLinkedin} from "react-icons/ai";
import { FaGithub } from "react-icons/fa";
import headshot from '../../public/rr-head-shot.jpg';
import css from '../../public/dev-icons/css.png';
import aws from '../../public/dev-icons/aws.png';
import bootstrap from '../../public/dev-icons/bootstrap.png';
import express from '../../public/dev-icons/express.png';
import github from '../../public/dev-icons/github.png';
import html from '../../public/dev-icons/html.png';
import js from '../../public/dev-icons/js.png';
import mongodb from '../../public/dev-icons/mongodb.png';
import next from '../../public/dev-icons/next.png';
import node from '../../public/dev-icons/node.png';
import postgresql from '../../public/dev-icons/postgresql.png';
import python from '../../public/dev-icons/python.png';
import react from '../../public/dev-icons/react.png';
import tailwind from '../../public/dev-icons/tailwind.png';
import { useClient } from 'next/client';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { TypeAnimation } from 'react-type-animation';
import { red } from "tailwindcss/colors";
import {EmblaCarousel} from './components/EmblaCarousel';
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";



export default function Home() {
  
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('black');
  const [fontWeight, setFontWeight] = useState('normal');
  const [animationTriggered, setAnimationTriggered] = useState(false);
  const {ref, inView} = useInView({
    triggerOnce: true,
    threshold: 0.1,
  });
  

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView && !animationTriggered) {
      setAnimationTriggered(true);
    }
  }, [inView, animationTriggered]);

  const CURSOR_CLASS_NAME = 'custom-type-animation-cursor';
  
  

  

  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? "dark" : ""}>
      
      <Head>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      

      <main className="bg-green-100  dark:bg-gray-900 relative ">
        <div className="h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-scroll px=10" >
        
          <nav className="px-5 pt-10 pb-10 mb-12 flex justify-between dark:text-white sticky top-0 z-50 bg-green-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
            <div class="fadeInUp">
              <h1 className="text-3xl font-burtons">R . R</h1>
            </div>
            <motion.div
              initial={{ x: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0.5 }}
              animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1.5 }}
            >
              <ul className="flex items-center" >
                <li className="ml-5 border-b-0">
                  <BsFillMoonStarsFill onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} className="cursor-pointer text-2xl"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="
                      text-black dark:text-white  px-4 py-2  ml-8
                      border-b-0 hover:border-b-4 hover:border-b-secondary dark:hover:border-b-secondary_dark" 
                    href="/#intro">Intro
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="
                      text-black dark:text-white  px-4 py-2  ml-8
                      border-b-0 hover:border-b-4 hover:border-b-secondary dark:hover:border-b-secondary_dark" 
                    href="/#about">About
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="
                      text-black dark:text-white  px-4 py-2  ml-8
                      border-b-0 hover:border-b-4 hover:border-b-secondary dark:hover:border-b-secondary_dark" 
                    href="/#projects">Projects
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="
                      text-black dark:text-white  px-4 py-2  ml-8
                      border-b-0 hover:border-b-4 hover:border-b-secondary dark:hover:border-b-secondary_dark" 
                    href="/#skills">Skills
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="
                      text-black dark:text-white  px-4 py-2  ml-8
                      border-b-0 hover:border-b-4 hover:border-b-secondary dark:hover:border-b-secondary_dark" 
                    href="">CV
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </motion.div>
          </nav>
     

      <section id="intro" className=" snap-start pt-20 py-20 flex-row h-4/5 mb-40 overflow-hidden">
        <div className="pt-20 relative px-40 flex flex-col md:flex-row space-y-5 items-center justify-evenly text-center md:text-left md:max-h-fit" >
          <div className="text-left p-10 min-w-[380px] w-380px whitespace-nowrap">
            <h4 className="text-2xl py-2 md:text-3xl dark:text-white">Hello, my name is </h4>
            <h2 className="text-5xl py-2 text-teal-600 font-medium md:text-6xl dark:text-teal-400">Ross Ritchie</h2>
            <span className="text-3xl dark:text-white">I am a </span> 
                <span className="text-3xl" style={{ color: textColor, fontWeight: fontWeight }}>
                  <TypeAnimation 
                    cursor={false}              
                    className={CURSOR_CLASS_NAME}
                    sequence={[
                      // Same substring at the start will only be typed out once, initially
                      ' corporate tax consultant.',
                      1000, // wait 1s before replacing "Mice" with "Hamsters"
                      ' Software developer',
                      () => setTextColor('#14b8a6'),
                      () => setFontWeight('Bold'),
                      3000,
                      ' Software developer.',                  
                      (el) => el.classList.remove('custom-type-animation-cursor'),                
                    ]}
                    wrapper="span"
                    speed={50}
                    style={{  display: 'inline-block' }}
                    class="custom-type-animation-cursor"
                    repeat={0}
                  />
                

                </span>
            <h4 className="text-1xl py-2 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">Based in Sydney</h4>
          </div>           
          <div className="w-[40px] min-w-[40px]">              
          </div>
          <div className="relative h-[380px] w-[380px] min-w-[380px] sm:w-[255px] bg-gradient-to-b from-teal-600 rounded-full overflow-hidden border-8 border-teal-500 border-solid" >
            <div className="rounded-full  overflow-hidden ">
              <Image src={headshot} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row items justify-center">        
          <div className="text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 py-1 px-2 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
            <a href="" target="blank"><AiFillLinkedin /></a>            
          </div>
          <div className="text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 py-1 px-2 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
            <a href="" target="blank"><FaGithub /></a>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>   
            

  <section id="about" className="snap-start pt-20 overflow-hidden h-full mb-40 bg-green-100 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white" ref={ref}>
      <div className="text-black text-3xl font-bold items-center justify-center pt-10 pb-5 flex flex-row">
        <img 
          src="" 
          className="rounded-lg  h-[40px] " 
        />
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold pl-5 dark:text-white">Chat GP-ME</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="pt-5 relative px-20 flex flex-col space-y-5 items-start justify-evenly text-center md:text-left md:max-h-fit">
        <div className="text-left text-2xl w-full max-w-7xl mx-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
            <h5 className="text-xl font-bold mb-2">User</h5>
            <div className="bg-teal-200 dark:bg-teal-800 p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg mb-5 w-full">
              {animationTriggered && (
                <TypeAnimation
                  cursor={false}
                  className="custom-type-animation-cursor"
                  style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line', height: 'auto', display: 'block' }}
                  sequence={[
                    `Tell me about yourself.`,
                    1000,                  
                    (el) => el.classList.remove('custom-type-animation-cursor'),
                  ]}
                  speed={{ type: 'keyStrokeDelayInMs', value: 30 }}
                  omitDeletionAnimation={true}
                  repeat={0}
                />
              )}
            </div>
            <h5 className="text-xl font-bold mb-2">Ross</h5>
            <div className="bg-teal-200 dark:bg-teal-800 p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg mb-5 w-full">
              {animationTriggered && (
                <TypeAnimation
                  cursor={false}
                  className="custom-type-animation-cursor"
                  style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line', height: 'auto', display: 'block' }}
                  sequence={[
                    ``,
                    2000,
                    `Sure!
                    
                    I started out as a corporate tax consultant and found that I really enjoyed using excel formulas to streamline analysing transaction data for tax purposes.
                    
                    I soon realised that the best part of my job was using algorithmic thinking to solve problems, speed up manual processes, and reduce errors.
                    
                    I figured that coding would be a better fit for this type of creative problem-solving and I would practice coding after finishing my day job as a tax consultant.
                    
                    The late-nights didn't bother me as my enthusiasm for coding meant that I could happily spend hours on a project that solved a practical problem.
                    
                    I worked in a team throughout my previous career and was also the main point of contact for the clients that I managed. As a result, I bring valuable skills that complement the technical skills required in software engineering.`,
                    
                    (el) => el.classList.remove('custom-type-animation-cursor'),
                  ]}
                  speed={{ type: 'keyStrokeDelayInMs', value: 30 }}
                  omitDeletionAnimation={true}
                  repeat={0}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=""></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="projects" className="h-screen snap-start pt- flex justify-center items-center">              
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-3/5 w-4/5 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <h1 className="text-3xl pb-5 dark:text-white">
          Projects
        </h1>
        <div className="h-full w-full m-auto py-5 px-0 relative group bg-teal-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden dark:bg-teal-800" >
          <EmblaCarousel />
        </div>  
      </div>
    </section>            
                                   
    <section id="skills" className=" h-screen snap-start pt-20">
      <div className="flex-col justify-center items-center text-center justify-items-end">
        <div className="h-[100px] pt-10">
          <h3 className="text-3xl py-1 dark:text-white">Skills</h3>                                        
        </div>
        <div id="grid-container" className="flex justify-center flex-wrap sm:px-0 sm:mx-0 dark:text-teal-800">
          <div className="
          justify-center justify-items-center text-center
          md:grid md:grid-cols-6 md:grid-rows-3 md:min-w-[900px] 
          sm:grid sm:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-rows-5 sm:min-w-[500px]">            
              <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[150px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
                <Image src={css}  objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px] py-10" />                
              </div>            
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={js} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={aws} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={bootstrap} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={express} layout="fill" objectFit="contain" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={github} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={html} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={mongodb} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={next} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={node} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={postgresql} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden">
              <Image src={python} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp 
            relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden  
            sm:col-start-2 md:col-start-3 " >
              <Image src={react} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            <div className="fadeInUp 
            relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden  
            sm:col-start-3 md:col-start-4 " >
              <Image src={tailwind} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div>
            {/* <div className="relative h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-gradient-to-b overflow-hidden  sm:col-start-3 sm:grid-row-start-4 " >
              <Image src={tailwind} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" classname="w-[100px] h-[100px]" />
            </div> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>  
    

                
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}


EmblaCarousel.jsx:
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react'
import { BsChevronCompactLeft, BsChevronCompactRight } from "react-icons/bs";

export const EmblaCarousel = () => {
  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel()

  useEffect(() => {    
    if (emblaApi) {
      
    }
  }, [emblaApi]);

  const scrollPrev = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollPrev()
  }, [emblaApi])

  const scrollNext = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollNext()
  }, [emblaApi])

  return (
    <div className="embla w-full h-full ">
      <div className="embla__viewport h-full dark:text-white" ref={emblaRef}>
        <div className="embla__container">

          <div className="embla__slide flex flex-row h-4/5 justify-center items-center">
            <div className='pl-5 pt-10 w-3/5 h-4/5 rounded-lg'>
              <img 
              src="" 
              className='object-center rounded-lg h-[400px]' 
              />
            </div>
            <div className='w-1/3 h-3/5 '>
              <div className=' px-10 py-15 text-center flex flex-col justify-center rounded-lg object-contain'>
                <h1 className='text-2xl pb-5 border-b-4  border-b-secondary'>AFFORDABLE COMMUTE FINDER</h1>
                <p className='pt-5'>
                  React App that calculates travel time (by car and public transport) between the users place 
                  of work and various recently sold properties. The results are grouped according to 15 minute 
                  time bands and sorted by affordability.
                </p>
                <p className='pt-10'>
                  This app uses the travel time and openstreet APIs to calculate co-ordinates and travel time 
                  for 1000s of properties
                </p>
              </div>              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="embla__slide flex flex-row h-4/5 justify-center items-center">
            <div className='pl-5 pt-10 w-3/5 h-4/5 rounded-lg'>
              <img 
              src="' 
              />
            </div>
            <div className='w-1/3 h-3/5 '>
              <div className=' px-10 py-15 text-center flex flex-col justify-center rounded-lg object-contain'>
                <h1 className='text-2xl pb-5 border-b-4  border-b-secondary'>METACRITIC FOR SONGS</h1>
                <p className='pt-5'>
                Python app that that generates a critical consensus for popular songs by scraping music publications 
                end of year lists.
                </p>
                <p className='pt-10'>
                Scraping done using beautiful soup. Makes calls to 2 different Spotify API end points.
                </p>
              </div>              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="embla__slide flex flex-row h-4/5 justify-center items-center">
            <div className='pl-5 pt-10 w-3/5 h-4/5 rounded-lg'>
              <img 
              src="" 
              className='object-center  rounded-lg' 
              />
            </div>
            <div className='w-1/3 h-3/5 '>
              <div className=' px-10 py-15 text-center flex flex-col justify-center rounded-lg object-contain'>
                <h1 className='text-2xl pb-5 border-b-4  border-b-secondary'>DOMESTIC SUPPLY MONITORING APP</h1>
                <p className='pt-5'>
                  Node.js App that links to MongDB that allows the user to monitor groceries and activities that
                   depend on that supply.
                </p>                
                <p className='pt-10'>
                  A shopping list can be generated for items that are running low. 
                </p>
              </div>              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="embla__slide flex flex-row h-4/5 justify-center items-center">
            <div className='pl-5 pt-20  w-3/5 h-4/5 rounded-lg'>
              <img 
              src="" 
              className='object-center rounded-lg' 
              />
            </div>
            <div className='w-1/3 h-3/5 '>
              <div className=' px-10 py-15 text-center flex flex-col justify-center rounded-lg object-contain'>
                <h1 className='text-2xl pb-5 border-b-4  border-b-secondary'>PERSONAL PORTFOLIO</h1>
                <p className='pt-5'>
                  Personal portfolio website created using Next.js/React. Styling done using tailwind, TypeAnimation 
                  and embla carousel.  
                </p>                
              </div>              
            </div>
          </div>       
        </div>
      </div>
      <button 
        className="embla__prev absolute left-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2
        bg-gray-800 text-white p-2 rounded-full ml-4"
        onClick={scrollPrev}
      >
        <BsChevronCompactLeft size={24}/>        
      </button>
      <button 
        className="embla__next absolute right-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2
         bg-gray-800 text-white p-2 rounded-full mr-4" 
         onClick={scrollNext}
      >
        <BsChevronCompactRight size={24}/>        
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}


File structure
I tried importing:
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

and including:
const router = useRouter();

also tried:
useEffect(() => {
    const loadRouter = async () => {
      const { useRouter } = await import('next/router');
      const router = useRouter();      
    };
    loadRouter();
  }, []); 

Neither of these worked. File structure
